# Xauth/X11 ssh forwarding errors with .Xauthority file not writable

Tags: ssh, xorg, forwarding, xauth

When logging in with `ssh -Y remotehost` I get the following error message:

> /usr/bin/xauth:  /home/hlovdal/.Xauthority not writable, changes will
>   be ignored

And xclock and similar fails to start. There is nothing wrong with the permissions
of the .Xauthority file despite the error message.

```
(hlovdal) remotehost:~>xclock
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
(hlovdal) remotehost:~>ls -l /home/hlovdal/.Xauthority
-rw-------. 1 hlovdal hlovdal 70 Jul 25 23:30 /home/hlovdal/.Xauthority
(hlovdal) remotehost:~>
```

What might be the cause here?

(This is between my two laptops where I have shh-ed back and forth hundreds of times before.)

---

Update:

While debugging further, xauth again complained that it could not write to .Xauthority
This does not make sense since the file is writable by my user,
and out of curiously I ran strace to see exactly what it tried to do.

```
(hlovdal) remotehost:~>xauth list
xauth:  /home/hlovdal/.Xauthority not writable, changes will be ignored
(hlovdal) remotehost:~>strace -oout -f -s9000 xauth list
xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/hlovdal/.Xauthority
(hlovdal) remotehost:~>tail out
16634 brk(0xf03000)                     = 0xf03000
16634 brk(0)                            = 0xf03000
16634 rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x4050d0, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3957035350}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
16634 rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x4050d0, [TERM], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3957035350}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
16634 rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x4050d0, [HUP], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3957035350}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
16634 rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {0x4050d0, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3957035350}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
16634 stat("/home/hlovdal/.Xauthority-c", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
16634 open("/home/hlovdal/.Xauthority-c", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
16634 write(2, "xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/hlovdal/.Xauthority\n", 66) = 66
16634 exit_group(1)                     = ?
(hlovdal) remotehost:~>ls -l .Xauthority*
-rw-------. 1 hlovdal hlovdal 70 Jul 25 23:30 .Xauthority
-rw-------. 2 hlovdal hlovdal  0 Jul 26 01:26 .Xauthority-c
-rw-------. 2 hlovdal hlovdal  0 Jul 26 01:26 .Xauthority-l
(hlovdal) remotehost:~>
```

This explains better why xauth fails since it fails to create .Xauthority-c.
But removing those two probably stale files does not help, they are recreated on the next ssh login.
syslog in remotehost contains the following related to the ssh login.

```
sshd[17551]: Accepted publickey for hlovdal from x.x.x.x port 36545 ssh2
sshd[17552]: fatal: mm_request_receive: read: Connection reset by peer
sshd[17551]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user hlovdal by (uid=0)
```

This mm_request_receive error message have never occured before, so I guess there is the clue for further debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an already known issue reported at [Redhat's bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=711156), so I'll "close" this question and continue reporting to that bug report.

Answer (score 19):

I had same issue after syncing my home folder on Ubuntu 12.04.
I resolved it using following commands:

```
rm ~/.Xaut*
```

Then I logged out and re-logged in. Following warning arisen:

```
/usr/bin/xauth:  file /home/iranice/.Xauthority does not exist
```

After that, Linux created `.Xauthority` file automatically. I logged out and re-logged in and everything was OK.

Comment: This is what fixes raspberry pi to Ubuntu 12.04 connection for me, both in the home.

Comment: I started having the same message after upgrading Unbuntu 17.10 on a Azure VM. I don't quite remember if I started seeing that message right after the upgrade when I remotely logged in with Putty or after i installed xrdp, since I wanted to have a remote Desktop Connection from my Windows 7 machine.
Anyways, your suggested solution fixed that.

Comment: for some reason my home `.Xauthority` directory was owned by `root:root` for some reason. but my home is owned by the correct user so I was able to remove the directory and then `ssh -X` and `ssh -Y` worked again.

Comment: Work in ubuntu 22.043 LTS, the message is gone on login motd

Answer (score 2):

For me I had this error :

`/usr/bin/xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/toto/.Xauthority`

because my /home partition was full.

Freeing some space on this partition solved this issue.

The strace command: `strace -oout -f -s9000 xauth list` has been useful in identifying the problem.

Comment: Might help to explain the command - I've taken a look at the [strace manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace), but I don't get what the arguement `-oout` means. Explaining it would turn a good answer, into an awesome one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me were SELinux permissions. They must be configured as follows:

```
chcon -Rv unconfined_u:object_r:xauth_home_t: s0 /PATH/.Xauthority
```

Comment: OPs problem was a known bug.  What "The problem" are you speaking about?  Please expand on your answer to include why this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was a permissions issue. Even if you deleted the file `.Xauthority`, it was recreated and was not writable. So I changed the owner and it worked:

`sudo chown user:user .Xauthority`

May be the file was created for root by default.